# How can I remove variables and any usage of them from my project? Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

The alt + delete way remove only definition of variable but I must remove all  occur of my variable and I couldn't find how to do that.

Comment: That wouldn't really make sense... how would you want IDE to know that you use a variable outside the local scope when it was defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically. For example, if the variable is passed as a parameter to a method, there is no way for an IDE to automatically remove that usage while maintaining correctness of the code.